# How to solve Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method stdClass::query()

Tags: php, mysqli

Can't figure out why I keep getting this error. Read many posts on this, but I don't understand when to use the stdClass() and when not.

Code:

```
$mysqli = new \stdClass();
$mysqli->connection = new mysqli($mysql_db_hostname, $mysql_db_user, $mysql_db_password, $mysql_db_database);
if($mysqli->connection->connect_error)
{
    echo "Error: Failed to make a MySQL connection, here is why: \n";
    echo "Errno: " . $mysqli->connect_errno . "\n";
    echo "Error: " . $mysqli->connect_error . "\n";
    exit;
}
else {
    printf("Succesfully connected to database.");
}

$sql = "SELECT * from customer";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {    <<==== ERROR
    printf("Success");
}
```

The first part, connecting to the database, seems to go fine. The error is thrown on the "if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql))" line. 
I tried changing it to:

```
if ($result = {object) $mysqli->query($sql))
```

but that didn't change anything.

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database connection is on `$mysqli->connection`, not `$mysqli`, so you would need to write

```
$result = $mysqli->connection->query($sql)
```

You have a similar issue with `$mysqli->connect_errno` and `$mysqli->connect_error`.

Note that more typical usage would be:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($mysql_db_hostname, $mysql_db_user, $mysql_db_password, $mysql_db_database);
```

then your code would run as is.

Comment: Yes, that solved it. Been editing so much converting an old project. Completely missed this.